# html razor: have the table create tds of uneven width

Tags: html, razor

I have created this not quite nice looking table:

[image]

This table is the result of the code I currently have.
See below.

I dont want it to look like this!

It is made up off two tds in each row.
As you can see, both tds in each row are always the same size.
However, some requiere less width, some more.

This is how I achieved this in razor;

```
<table class="uneven">
    @{

        for (int i = 0; i < Model.JobFacts.Count(); i++)
        {
            @*create new row every 2nd element*@
            if(i % 2 == 0) 
            {
                <tr></tr>
            }
            <td>
                <div class="jobfacts">
                    <p style="font-size:13px;">@Model.JobFacts[i]</p>
                </div>
            </td>
        }
    }
</table>
```

I have already added a class called "uneven" to my table.

What can I put into the css there, that the table tds end where the white background ends?
So each row has a different lenght.

THank you!

Answer (score 0):

`<td>` elements need to be *inside* `<tr>` elements, not next to them.  One way you might be able to achieve this is to wrap the whole loop in a `<tr>` and then conditionally break it with a new closing/opening `<tr>` every second element, for example:

```
<table class="uneven">
    <tr>
    @{
        for (int i = 0; i < Model.JobFacts.Count(); i++)
        {
            @*create new row every 2nd element*@
            if(i % 2 == 0) 
            {
                </tr><tr>
            }
            <td>
                <div class="jobfacts">
                    <p style="font-size:13px;">@Model.JobFacts[i]</p>
                </div>
            </td>
        }
    }
    </tr>
</table>
```

This has potential for an off-by-one bug and would need to be tested of course.  At worst you'd likely just need to change the `if` condition.  (For example, you may need to check something like `i != 0 && i % 2 == 0`)  But the overall idea is that every `<td>` is always inside of a `<tr>`, and every two elements you close the current `<tr>` and open a new one.